# Why is the if condition is not working properly?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have attached my code below. It's like a hotel bot. The if-conditions are not working.

```
types = ["Chinese", "Italian", "Indian"]

Chinese = ["Fried Rice or Noodles"]
Italian = ["Pizza or Pasta"]
Indian = ["Idly or Dosa"]

input(name.title() + ", What type of cuisine do you like in " + str(types) +"?: \n")

if input == Chinese:
    order1 = input("Would You like " + str(Chinese) + "?\n")
    if "Fried Rice":
          no1 = input("How many Fried Rice would you like?: \n")
          print("Your " + no1 + " " + order1 + " will be ready in a moment")
    if "Noodles" :
        no2 = input("How many Noodles would you like?: \n")
        print("Your " + no2 + " " + order1 + " will be ready in a moment")

elif input == Italian:
    order2 = input("Would You like " + str(Italian) + "?\n")
    if "Pizza":
        no1 = input("How many Pizzas would you like?: \n")
        print("Your " + no1 + " " + order2 + " will be ready in a moment")
    if "Pasta":
        no2 = input("How many Pastas would you like?: \n")
        print("Your " + no2 + " " + order2 + " will be ready in a moment")

if input == Indian :
    order3 = input("Would You like " + str(Indian) + "?\n")
    if "Idly":
        no1 = input("How many Idlys would you like?: \n")
        print("Your " + no1 + " " + order3 + " will be ready in a moment")
    if "Dosa":
        no2 = input("How many Dosas would you like?: \n")
        print("Your " + no2 + " " + order3 + " will be ready in a moment")
```

Can someone show me the mistake I have made. And give a solution for it.

Comment: You should add a tag for the language in question.

Comment: What are the if statements supposed to do? What do they not do?

Comment: Please, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, extract a [mcve] from your code and include both what output it gives you and what you'd expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign anything to a variable called `input`  you probably also want to check if they type 'Chinese' not the value of the variable `Chinese` . Something like

```
user_input = input(name.title() + ", What type of cuisine do you like in " + str(types) +"?: \n")

if user_input == "Chinese":
    ...
```